# Nested stores in Extjs4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I was just wondering if we can have a nested stores, similar to nested models in Extjs4.
i am thinking this just because, i have a 10 drop downs and 10 grids which uses the same model. hence i have 10 stores for drop down and 10 stores for grid.

among 10 drop down stores, 2 dropdown will make a ajax call to retrieve the data from server and other stores will use the response data of above 2 and load their independent store using the response. similar applies to grid also.

So is this the right approach.? and any disadvantage of having multiple stores(about 20 :O) on the same page.

Kindly suggest. :)

Small Update to Clear my question.
i am not referring as nested stores because it is reffering to same model. in Extjs4 we can have a single ABCModel.js and define many components which exted Model. Hence to clear my question again, I have 10 stores(ie.,, 10 .js files) and 10 grids (again 10.js files for stores). So is this the right approach or can we push all these under single .js file.

Thanks
Punith

Answer (score 0):

It's not really "nested" stores... The fact that they are using same model has nothing to do with nested.

I would not worry about number of stores on the page more then I would worry about number of grids for example. Stores in your case would just play role of arrays for data.

Load two (or four) stores from the server, and then create local copies for other controls. You won't be able to use same store object for different controls if they show different set of data. What you need to do is to filter one store and create a clone of result in the other store object. And since you basically need only one or two fields in these local stores - you might want to create a simple model ([id, name] or something like that).

Comment: i was not referring as nested stores because it is reffering to same model. in Extjs4 we can have a single ABCModel.js and define many components which exted Model. Hence to clear my question again, I have 10 stores(ie.,, 10 .js files) and 10 grids (again 10.js files for stores). So is this the right approach or can we push all these under single .js file.

Comment: Thanks Sha, i was lil bit under confusion here. and for this suggestion "What you need to do is to filter one store and create a clone of result in the other store object". Yes i am doing exactly the same. in the response of Store A i am taking out the data based on Root and loadData() on store B.  Thanks Punith